# How do you scissor without LWJGL? JScissor?

Tags: java, components

I am writing an application without OpenGL (LWJGL) and I know you can use GL_SCISSOR in LWJGL but how would you do it without LWJGL? There is not an JScissor class and it'd be useful for my GUI.

What is scissoring?
Scissoring is like a rendering cutoff point. You set your bounds (x, y, width and height)
Then particular things set within those bounds can not be rendered outside of them.
For example a achievement tree like in Minecraft.

It'd be great if anyone could help.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what "scissor" does and ask if anything in Java's GUI code does that.